# Prove by induction that $R$ (subring of matrices $3\times3$ over Galois field) satisfies $(xy)^{k}=x^{k}y^{k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need to prove by induction that $R$, which is subring of matrices $3\times3$ over Galois field defined by

$$ R=\Biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\
0 & a & d\\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}\, a,\, b,\, c,\, d\in GF(p)\Biggr\} $$

satisfies $(xy)^{k}=x^{k}y^{k}$ for every $x, y\in R$ and $k>2$.

I proved that this is true for $k=3$ and claiming that it is true for $k$ I get that

$\Biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\
0 & a & d\\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e & f & g\\
0 & e & h\\
0 & 0 & e
\end{pmatrix}\Biggr\}^{k+1} = \Biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\
0 & a & d\\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e & f & g\\
0 & e & h\\
0 & 0 & e
\end{pmatrix}\Biggr\}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\
0 & a & d\\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e & f & g\\
0 & e & h\\
0 & 0 & e
\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\
0 & a & d\\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}e & f & g\\
0 & e & h\\
0 & 0 & e
\end{pmatrix}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\
0 & a & d\\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e & f & g\\
0 & e & h\\
0 & 0 & e
\end{pmatrix}
 $

However, I don't know how to continue because this ring isn't commutative. Could anyone help me to finish this proof by induction, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix}{}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}^3
\begin{pmatrix}{}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}^3
 = \begin{pmatrix}{}1&3&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}{}1&0&0\\0&1&3\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}{}1&3&9\\0&1&3\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \\ 
\left(\begin{pmatrix}{}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}{}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)^3
 = \begin{pmatrix}{}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}^3 
 = \begin{pmatrix}{}1&3&6\\0&1&3\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\\ 
$$

Comment: Ok, perhaps we should assume $p=3$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : then we can just pick $k=5$ instead of $3$. With general $k$, the topright coefficients are $k^2$ and $k(k+1)/2$, their difference is $k(k-1)/2$ and there is no prime $p$ dividing all of those numbers.